# Using PHP to generate a signed RTMP URL for AWS

Tags: php, actionscript-3, amazon-web-services

I've created a PHP function that generates a signed URL for AWS. I've used it for all kinds of http content.

I now need to use it to generate a signed RTMP link. I saw in the docs, that I am supposed to just use the folder/filename without extension.

Given my bucket structure is `dms/myfile.mp4` I pass, `dms/myfile` into my PHP function and it generates the hashed URL. The hashed URL looks like this:

```
dms/myfile?Expires=1409073611&Signature=Iw2Df~JXc4psMp0f8qQz8WtxCbW54ErcN--CwCEGo7yf8Fg1wH-qFY9AjCvsV04w0piWoRzlYgEh6uz6tOaCwiEBZPn41FYFStvq3VXh34s1bEi4HQEDh0~nCXW5RZaUnHGcFWzK25HddmfY-4Yvw5fIHaIxMwIv9HZ3yIo0S~HqKO2h0ZKnf4sJ6vDeiVQ3Lx73bKJQV2kISIybu7QyUGQTH0XLWCAz5hq-zVuz~xbqcHqO27~sVdSXhPw4jLDGDnnhp6oXWF-SV-0eK8QImu1saWlCxr3bWVA1MTrNExw0LsTbjJGLA1Vsd74CzI6mVR8V6NjX82ZONAcVPAs4QQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAI3ZSOLRDPPSNWPDA
```

In my AS3 code, I successfully connect to the RTMP distribution server and then I attempt to play the dynamic streaming item as:

```
mp4:dms/myfile?Expires=1409073611&Signature=Iw2Df~JXc4psMp0f8qQz8WtxCbW54ErcN--CwCEGo7yf8Fg1wH-qFY9AjCvsV04w0piWoRzlYgEh6uz6tOaCwiEBZPn41FYFStvq3VXh34s1bEi4HQEDh0~nCXW5RZaUnHGcFWzK25HddmfY-4Yvw5fIHaIxMwIv9HZ3yIo0S~HqKO2h0ZKnf4sJ6vDeiVQ3Lx73bKJQV2kISIybu7QyUGQTH0XLWCAz5hq-zVuz~xbqcHqO27~sVdSXhPw4jLDGDnnhp6oXWF-SV-0eK8QImu1saWlCxr3bWVA1MTrNExw0LsTbjJGLA1Vsd74CzI6mVR8V6NjX82ZONAcVPAs4QQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAI3ZSOLRDPPSNWPDA
```

**Note the 'mp4' before the signed URL**

For some reason when I attempt to play the video, I get the error

`Failed to play dms/myfile; stream not found.`

Anyone know what I am doing wrong here? I can assure you the file does exist.

Answer (score 0):

Their are couple of reasons behind this error

1. If the file is mp4 then use mp4:{file_name_without_extension}?signed_url
2. If the file is flv then use {file_name_with_extension}?signed_url
3. If you are creating time based signed url then time may be over when you are accessing the url. You need to increase the time Or need to check your server time because time may be cause.
4. Check file exists and you are using same RTMP network for accessing the bucket where file exists.
5. Also while creating RTMP network you should used Restrict Viewer Access
   (Use Signed URLs) - Yes

Comment: 1. it is an mp4 and I am creating the signed url without the mp4 which is the first snippet I posted. The second snippet is what I am passing to my AS3 player. 2. Not FLV 3. Will try increasing the time 4. definitely access the correct bucket 5. I'll look into this. I did not setup this bucket